# How to store the user name from _Loginpartial.cshtml and use it in a .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```html
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">
    Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!
</a>
```

I basically want to take the `@UserManager.GetUserName(User)` and store it as a variable and use it on a controller file to compare it inside a SQL Command. I need to get the current user's emailed so i can print out specific things from a database regarding that person.

```
namespace FinalAdminPortal.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]

    public class HomeController : Controller
     {

        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public HomeController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.configuration = config;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah its a controller file.I want to take the email of the user and store it as a variable so i can use it in the controller file to compare in a SQL command to print out a row in a database that matches the users email.

Comment: You could call `UserManager.GetUserName(User)` from `Controller`, there is no need to pass it from cshtml to cs. Register `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` like `IConfiguration `.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject the UserManager in the constructor of our controller like this:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
public YourController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
    this.userManager = userManager;
}
```

Then fetch your corrent user:

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Depending on what you want to do it may be a good idea not to run quers directly inside the controller and create an method in some kind of User-Repo as abstraction.

Comment: Where exactly would i place this in my controller?

Comment: @DanielJiwani DY of `UserManager` In the constructor, which  is `HomeController` in your added source code. The `GetUserAsync` call goes to the Action `(IActionResult)` where you need information about the logged in user.